# Laravel Change Redirection part if the Auth's session expires

Tags: php, laravel, session, redirect, authentication

When the session expires my users are getting redirected to `/login` however they should be redirected to `/backoffice/login`, does anyone know in which file I can change the redirection part?

Comment: Serious question, why is this getting downvoted so much? Because it contains no code? I don't think that code is necessary for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Exception Handler is what takes all unauthenticated requests and handles them in the way you need.

It will look something like this:

*app/Exceptions/Handler.php*

```
/**
 * Convert an authentication exception into an unauthenticated response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    return redirect()->guest('login');
}
```

You can adjust the redirect by changing `return redirect()->guest('login');` to `return redirect()->guest('backoffice/login');`